# React PrivateRoute auth route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a basic react auth app, right now the routes /signup and /login work when I run this repo with my `.env.local` file that contains firebase auth variables.
https://github.com/MartinBarker/react-auth-app

I am trying to make it so that the '/' route that points to Dashboard will only be accessible for a user who is currently signed in, and if a user is not signed in but tries to access the '/' route they will be redirected to the '/login' page.

But whenever I use the route

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" element={Dashboard} />
```

my chrome devtools console shows a blank page with error messages:

```
index.tsx:24 Uncaught Error: [PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

my PrivateRoute.js looks like this:

```
// This is used to determine if a user is authenticated and
// if they are allowed to visit the page they navigated to.

// If they are: they proceed to the page
// If not: they are redirected to the login page.
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from '../Contexts/AuthContext'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  // Add your own authentication on the below line.
  //const isLoggedIn = AuthService.isLoggedIn()

  const { currentUser } = useAuth()
  console.log('PrivateRoute currentUser = ', currentUser)

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        currentUser ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          //redirect to /login if user is not signed in
          <Navigate to={{ pathname: '/login'}} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Im not sure why this error is occurring, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour seems to have changed in ReactRouter V6 here is the solution we came up with for a project.

**Private route**
*Re-creating the users question code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from '../Contexts/AuthContext'

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {

  // Add your own authentication on the below line.
  //const isLoggedIn = AuthService.isLoggedIn()

  const { currentUser } = useAuth()
  console.log('PrivateRoute currentUser = ', currentUser)

  return (
    <>
      {
      currentUser ? (
          children
        ) : (
          //redirect to /login if user is not signed in
          <Navigate to={{ pathname: '/login'}} />
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

**Typescript**
*Our actual code implementation of this issue

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isAuthenticated, isAuthLoading } = useAuth();
  const { user, isLoadingUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  // Handle users which are not authenticated
  // For example redirect users to different page

  // Show loader if token is still being retrieved
  if (isAuthLoading || isLoadingUser) {
    // TODO: show full page loader
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }

  // Proceed with render if user is authenticated
  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

**Router**

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path={routes.user.accountSignup.path}
      element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <AccountSignup />
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: I'm using .js files, but the line `const PrivateRoute: React.FC = ({ children }) => {` and `React.FC` says there is a type annotation error and can only be used in typescript files.

Comment: The answer was intended as a guide not to be copy-pasted as I said in the note. I have updated the answer to use your code have a look I am not sure if it works but essentially it should no longer return a Route.

Comment: Implementing these changes seems to work wheim signed out, it redirects to /login. but once I login and go to '/' route which loads Dashboard: ```react-dom.development.js:25058 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.```

Comment: I can't be 100% sure of the issue but I have updated the code to what I think the problem is. Basically previously you were passing the component as a prop where as now it is just children.

Comment: This seems to work, except if I log out I get a message in console that says ```Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at Dashboard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:170:76``` im wondering if some part of this code is causing a memory leak? I dont want to ignore this error

Comment: It is really hard to debug that from what you have provided as that could be happening in so many places sorry. It is also very different from the original question. There is very little logic in the private route so I doubt it is related but hard to tell since before the private route you weren't rendering any of your application. Potentially change the child component to a simple one and see if the error still occurs.